# Is $e=c(p-1)$ the only solution for $a^e=1\mod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Fermat's little theorem states  $a^{p-1}=1\mod p$ for a prime $p$ and $gcd(a,p)=1$, but does the inverse also work so that $e=c(p-1)$ is the only solution for $a^e=1\mod p$ if the solution must fit any $a$? It looks obvious to me, but I cannot reason why...

If I would use the above in a proof, could I then simply state and use it or should I supply a proof myself? How would that proof then look like?

Comment: Cf. [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Comment: $2^3 = 8 \equiv  1 \mod{7}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converse does not hold , if $\ a\ $ is arbitary. What we can say is that the smallest positive integer $\ k\ $ with $\ a^k\equiv 1\mod p\ $ (called the order of $\ a\ $ modulo $\ p\ $, denoted with $\ ord_p(a)\ $) must be a divisor of $\ p-1\ $. We can then say $\ a^e\equiv 1\mod p\iff k\mid e\ $.

A base $\ a\ $ for which we have $\ k=p-1\ $ (in this case the above converse is actually true) is called a primitive root modulo $\ p\ $. Since such a primitive root exists for every prime $\ p\ $, the answer to the question is "yes".

Comment: Sorry, a lot of information for a non-math like me. Do I get this right: from the Carmichael function wikipage I read (intro) that $m=\lambda(n)$ so that $a^m=1\mod n$. But if $n$ is prime then $\lambda(n)=n-1$ (a little lower on the page). So if $n$ is prime then $m=n-1$ is the minimal solution and then in fact all multiples of $n-1$ are a solution?

Comment: $\lambda(n)$ is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $a^m\equiv 1\mod n$ holds for EVERY $a$ coprime to $n$ (Not only for prime $n$). If $n$ is prime, we have $m=n-1$, so there is at least one $a$ for which the minimal exponent is $n-1$ and therefore only the multiples of $n-1$ are solutions.

Comment: OK thanks for the confirmation and your time.